# Auto reload proxy.pac file in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy, proxy.pac

I am using proxy.pac file to route my traffic in chrome browser.Whenever I change my proxy.pac file I need to manually click `reapply settings` button here `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` to make it work. My proxy.pac file will change frequently so it is difficult to manually apply changes every time.Is there a way to automate this process like any add ons or scripts.

`Foxyproxy` add on has a option to reload pac file automatically in Firefox but in chrome that option is not provided.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/31946, there's also [proxy API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy), try it.

Comment: @wOxxOm : Hi thanks for your suggestions unfortunately it doesn't get auto reloaded as mentioned in  crbug.com/31946. I waited for more than 25 minutes but  no changes .Still I need to manually apply the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just Modified your code based on Pac-Script proxy setting. It means it works only if you have proxy mode pacscript thats it.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   var errorHandler = new ProxyErrorHandler();
   var persistedSettings = ProxyFormController.getPersistedSettings();     

        if (persistedSettings !== null) {           
            if (persistedSettings.regular.mode == 'pac_script') {
               // Do something every 5 seconds                
               setInterval(function() {
                  // call URL with random string to avoid URL cache
                  persistedSettings.regular.pacScript.url = 'myfile/path/for/fun.pac?nocache'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
                  chrome.proxy.settings.set({'value': persistedSettings.regular});
             }, 5000);
            }               
            chrome.proxy.settings.set({'value': persistedSettings.regular});
        }       
});
```

Comment: That's an improvement; yet still it would be better not to rely on the-rest-of-the-sample-code for this.

Comment: Yep. Its been modified based on our needs. Is it need any more dependency? else any better solution much appreciated. Thanks! Xan

Answer (score 1):

Download this sample chrome extension `https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/proxy_configuration.zip` and replace the background.js with below script.Load this extension in developer mode.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var errorHandler = new ProxyErrorHandler();
   var persistedSettings = ProxyFormController.getPersistedSettings();   

    setInterval(function() {
         // Do something every 5 seconds   
        if (persistedSettings !== null) {
            chrome.proxy.settings.set({'value': 'myfile/path/for/fun.pac'});
        }
    }, 5000);

});
```

This will reload PAC file every 5 seconds.

Comment: Why all the complications, if the essence of your solution is calling `chrome.proxy.settings.set` on an interval? Also, I'm not sure your syntax for this is correct.

Comment: As far as I understand, the correct call would be with `value: {mode: "pac_script", pac_script: {url: "path/to/file.pac"}}`

Comment: I tried the above code in my background.js and it is working fine.I am new to  chrome extension so I am not sure what I am doing is efficient way but that is working fine for me.

Comment: I suspect that what your code really achieves is trying to feed Chrome with an improper configuration, it somehow causes it to re-read its old configuration. Needless to say it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, will try to improve my code.